# <!> Exception: if(outOfBound) dialog.close();

Tags: blackberry

Can I close itself in a dialog if touch event happens out side of the dialog field? I can close it quite well on the opposite case as following code shows:

```
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message)
{
    int x = message.getX( 1 );
    int y = message.getY( 1 );
    if( x < 0 || y < 0 || x > getExtent().width || y > getExtent().height ) {
        // Outside the field
//      close();//? can't be closed properly
        return false;
    }

    switch( message.getEvent() ) {

        case TouchEvent.UNCLICK:
        close();//? can be closed properly
        return true;
    }
    return super.touchEvent( message );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! Thank you all the same.
It is of great help if you can talk to some one when get stuck.

But I still have no ideas what's the difference between these two:

```
protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message)
{
    int x = message.getX( 1 );
    int y = message.getY( 1 );
    boolean isOutOfBounds = false;

    if( x < 0 || y < 0 || x > getExtent().width || y > getExtent().height ) {
        // Outside the field
//      close();//!
//      return true;

        isOutOfBounds = true;
    }

    switch( message.getEvent() ) {

        case TouchEvent.UNCLICK:

        // close in TouchEvent, if out of bounds                    
        if(isOutOfBounds)
        {
            close();
            return true;
        }


        close();                                   
            return true;
    }
    return super.touchEvent( message );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.
instead of writing just close write this. hope it will work.

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater ( new Runnable() 
{ 
      public void run () 
                        {
                            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new MyTripScreen());
                            close();
                        }
                    }
                );
```